# how to get the positions for layout in custom adapter in android?

Tags: android

I am using CustomAdapter with a xml of four LinearLayouts as horizontal the xml is like

xml code:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
            android:src="@drawable/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="ff"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="99.99"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Laundry"
                android:textColor="#3A9ED4"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
            android:src="@drawable/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVal1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="ff"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="99.99"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Dry Clean"
                android:textColor="#3A9ED4"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
            android:src="@drawable/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVal2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="ff"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="99.99"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Stream Iron"
                android:textColor="#3A9ED4"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

in this I getting the images textview data from server like this

```
holder.ll1 = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ll1);
                holder.ll2 = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ll2);
                holder.ll3 = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ll3);
                holder.tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                holder.tv2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
                holder.tv3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv5);
                holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
                holder.tvVal = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
                holder.tvVal1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal1);
                holder.tvVal2 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal2);
```

setting the data for view components

```
            holder.tv1.setText(wash_v.get(position));
            holder.tv2.setText(dry_v.get(position));
            holder.tv3.setText(iron_v.get(position));
```

here the problem is I am not getting the individual layout position so how to get the positions of single layout position?

Comment: I'm not getting your question but if you want to get position of item properly then you should set the tag as `setTag()` in `getView()` method and use the tag to get the position as `getTag()`

Comment: how we can set the tag for linearlayout  i think holder.ll1.setTag()

Comment: Can you explain me   why do you need the layout's position, so that i can provide you some alternate solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tag to the view that's getting inflated every time.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    ...
    ...
}
```

This tag will be attached to every item of `listview` and you get that tag using `getTag()` method whenever needed.

Comment: i need linearlayout position how u can say

Comment: your linear layout is the view of listview item right? So listview item tag itself is the tag of your linear layout.